# Normal Firewall Action if Responder's Source Address Changes

Tags: udp, ip, port, firewall, windows-firewall

When I request a webpage from my computer, that request goes through two firewalls
(one on my Windows 10 computer plus one on my ISP-provided modem router).  There
are no outgoing firewall rules and let's say my packet gets released into the
internet backbone with source 1.2.3.4:9 and destination 11.12.13.14:19.  For the
reply, I understand that both firewalls will temporarily allow packets with
destination 1.2.3.4:9 (or the NAT-mapped LAN address behind my router), but do
the firewalls also care about the response's source?

What if the response had a source of 11.12.13.14:20 (i.e., with a new port)?
Or what if the response had a completely different source of 91.92.93.94:99?

For a UDP connection, it seems like there would be some value in allowing a quick
change of the server source.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, I did some tests with raw data frames.  Windows' Firewall
itself never dropped responses, no matter how I changed source info, but every
application and API I found seems careful to make sure that the source address
and port are never changed.

But, the ISP router (actually it might be a machine outside of the router that
is in the ISP's control) did seem to provide a firewall against changes.  In
particular, if I open a UDP connection from one computer to another computer
across the internet (so now there are two ISPs to think about), all worked
fine if I used the standard addresses.  But, changing just one bit of the
response's source port caused the packet to get dropped by the initiator's ISP.

I guess my ISP is trying to protect me and thereby going beyond the required
LAN-to-WAN NAT forwarding.